# V+O+to+V analysis

Tags: grammar

I promised her a birthday party./I promised her to get her a pizza.//I forbade her sugar./I forbade her to enter my office.

Are these two to-infinitives direct objects? If someone sees the second to-infinitive as a complement while seeing the first one as an object, only because the agent of first one is the speaker himself and the agent of the second one is the object in the front, I think it's very unreasonable. I think we should see the second one both as a direct object and as a complement. We should be flexible. Both analyses are very reasonable. Have something to say?

Comment: _Promise_ is a unique verb. It has an indirect object, but the subject of its infinitive complement is the same as the **subject** of _promise_, not its indirect object. _I ordered him to take out the garbage_ = he takes it out, but _I promised him to take out the gargabe_ = I take it out.

Comment: And, by the way, "V+O+to+V" is not the way to think or talk about this. There are too many different constructions that can be described this way. Think about clauses used as object or subject (and therefore as noun phrases).

Comment: I really think you ought to think about these verb+preposition phrases as unique. For example, "put in" means to insert, "put down" means to kill, "put up with" means to endure. In other cases certain prepositions wouldn't make sense: "put of" doesn't make sense in its own right as a verbal phrase, nor does "put from" or "put until." You can especially see this with other verbs: "consist of" makes sense, but "contain of" or "comprise of" make no sense.

Answer (score -1):

Both of your second sentences are non-standard, at a minimum, and possibly ungrammatical.

> I promised her to get her a pizza.

I don't know anyone who would say this like that.  I would either say "I promised to get her a pizza" or, if you wanted to be clear who you made the promise to, "I promised her that I would get her a pizza." or just "I promised her a pizza"

> I forbade her to enter my office.

You are mixing tenses here. This should either be "I forbid her to enter my office" (present tense) or "I forbade her from entering my office"(past tense).

Comment: I agree with your first half. I think most sentences other than "I forbid/forbade **you** to ..." sound at best unusual....'